# How to install netgear AC1200 (model A6150), wifi dongle

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, devices, dkms

I am trying to install my new netgear wifi usb dongle AC1200 (A6150) on my Kubuntu 20.04.
More specifically my system setup:

```
mainline 1.0.18
Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Architecture: amd64
Running kernel: 5.19.17-051917-generic
```

The system can read the device via lsusb which reads as follows: `Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9055 NetGear, Inc. A6150`; however I cannot manage to install it properly nor know if I am using it.
Unfortunately where I live the internet is so bad it is barely workable with, so I hope that by stabilizing my connection I get minimal improvements. Please keep things simple as Linux is my hobby and I am an amateur but now I ended up with my personal laptop to work with.

HERE ARE SOME OUTPUT:

-with sudo dkms status

> rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg: added
> rtl88x2bu, 5.6.1: added
> rtl88x2bu, 5.8.7.1: added

-with sudo lshw -C network

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 07
       serial: 8c:ec:4b:09:68:79
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.17-051917-generic firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d2204000-d2204fff memory:d2200000-d2203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: b0:52:16:12:73:09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.19.17-051917-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.1.128 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:131 memory:d2000000-d21fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: ham0
       serial: 7a:79:19:36:f3:c2
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full ip=25.54.243.194 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

-with iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"connection 1"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.432 GHz  Access Point: AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:475   Missed beacon:0

ham0      no wireless extensions.
```

I changed what I think it is sensitive data in the iwconfig output.

Comment: try `sudo dkms install rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1` and report any errors, if there are no errors reboot

Comment: this is what I get: `Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1

DKMS: add completed.
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 6.0.1-060001-generic cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-6.0.1-060001-generic package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located`